# Fragment button click is not working in Marshmallow version of android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Fragment button click is not working in Marshmallow version of android. I have three fragment a1, a2 and a3 all fragment have a button in a1 button click goto a2 and a2 button click goto a3 it working fine in lower version then 23 but in 23 api a2 button click is not working.

**Fragment a1**

```
public class A1Fragment extends RootFragment {

public A1Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a1, container, false);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterNextFragment();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void enterNextFragment() {
    A2Fragment a2Fragment = new A2Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Store the Fragment in stack
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, a2Fragment).commit();
}
}
```

**Fragement a2**

```
public class A2Fragment extends RootFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button;

public A2Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a2, container, false);

    button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}


private void enterNextFragment() {
    A3Fragment a2Fragment = new A3Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Store the Fragment in stack
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, a2Fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.next_button:

            enterNextFragment();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**Fragment a3**

```
public class A3Fragment extends RootFragment {

protected ViewPager pager;

public A3Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a3, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);

   /* getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new A3Fragment());*/

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pager.setCurrentItem(2);
            enterNextFragment();
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}


private void enterNextFragment() {

    C1Fragment a2Fragment = new C1Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Store the Fragment in stack
    /*transaction.addToBackStack(null);*/
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, a2Fragment).commit();
}

}
```

Comment: try removing switch case from a2 and use it as you have used click listener in other two

Comment: why are you using getChildFragmentManager()? is your fragment inside another fragment?

Comment: you have to use getFragmentManager or getSupportFragmentManager instead of getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: i was used both getFragmentManager and getSupportFragmentManager but its not working..